# 変数の使用方法について

Tags: swift, spritekit

```
var a = 3
let b = SKAction.moveByX(-100, y: 0.0, duration: 2)
```

`duration`の値に変数aを入れたい場合どのようにしたら良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

このようにしたらエラーが出てうまくいかなかったということでしょうか。

```
var a = 3
let b = SKAction.moveByX(-100, y: 0.0, duration: a)
```

該当のメソッドはSwiftではこのようなシグニチャーになっています。
[+ moveByX:y:duration:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/moveByX:y:duration:)

```
class func moveByX(_ deltaX: CGFloat,
                 y deltaY: CGFloat,
          duration sec: NSTimeInterval) -> SKAction
```

durationに与える引数は、NSTimeInterval型ですから、変数自体をNSTimeIntervalとして宣言するか、

```
var a: NSTimeInterval = 3
let b = SKAction.moveByX(-100, y: 0.0, duration: a)
```

もしくはキャストして型を合わせてやらないといけません。

```
var a = 3 //<-この書き方だとaはInt型になります。
let b = SKAction.moveByX(-100, y: 0.0, duration: NSTimeInterval(a))
```

(NSTimeIntervalはSwiftではDoubleのtypealiasですので、上記の型名の部分はDoubleでも構いません。)

もしお聞きになりたい内容と違っていたら、コメントかご質問を修正するかたちでお知らせください。
一般的な質問の書き方の話になりますが、うまくいかなかった例があるのであれば、その場合のコードとエラーメッセージ等も質問に含められたほうが、より的確な回答を得られる可能性が高まりますので、できるだけそれらの情報を盛り込むようにしてください。

Comment: 非常にわかりやすい回答ありがとうございます。
理解することができました＾ー＾
次回質問する際はそのように書かせていただきます。
ありがとうございました！